# Heroku app randomly says "no such app", refreshing the page multiple times fixes it

Tags: heroku

My app: https://grafulator.herokuapp.com

When I initially visit the app it gives me the default "No such app" heroku page, if I refresh it repeatedly a few times my app will then load.

[image]

I was on a free dyno, but just upgraded to a hobby to see if it would resolve it, but it hasn't yet.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

The app is Go using julienschmidt's httprouter, frontend is ReactJS

Comment: It works fine in my browser, maybe the dyno was asleep.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently my app got out of sync with heroku routers, creating a ticket with them resolved the issue.